# Matrix Multiplication in C always returning 0?

Tags: c, matrix, multiplication, zero

I've been trying to do basic matrix calculations in C, but multiplying two matrices together always returns a value of 0. After reading others who had similar problems, I still do not understand why this is happening. Here is the multiplication function:

```
double** MatrixMultiplication(double** matrixA, double** matrixB,
                              int sizeXA, int sizeYA, int sizeXB, int sizeYB) 
{
    double** matrixC = MatrixAllocate(sizeXA, sizeYB);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeXA; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeYB; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < sizeXA; k++) {
                matrixC[i][j] += matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return matrixC;
}
```

And this is the code for the `MatrixAllocate` function:

```
double** MatrixAllocate(int sizeX, int sizeY) {
    double **matrix;
    matrix = (double**)malloc(sizeX*sizeof(double*));
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
        matrix[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeY*sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Both MatrixA and MatrixB are filled by the user, and when printed they have non-zero data.

Comment: Return value of 0 means, that matrix has all members 0, or matrixC output from MatrixMultiplication is NULL ?

Comment: You have a bug here: `for (int k = 0; k < sizeXA; k++)`, that should be `k < sizeXB` (or `sizeYA`). But that shouldn't manifest as always getting 0.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: Works here on a simple example, as expected. The problem is most likely in the calling code.

Comment: It works. Put some code where you are calling MatrixMultiplication and building matrixA and matrixB. Also, consider suggestion by @DanielFischer.

Comment: Allocating each row (or column) individually (plus one array of pointer) is not really efficient. Allocating the whole matrix in one seems to be better. Alloc one with malloc(sizeX*sizeY*sizeof(double)). Easier and more efficient to allocate and free.

Answer (score 1):

Something else is your problem because this works just fine for me.  Notice I've modified my versions of your methods ever so slightly. (changed method names because only class start with Capitals, added ability to control initial values in a matrix creation to not be all 0's to seed for testing.)

The output as expected was:

> Foo
>   Row [0]: 0 1 2
>   Row [1]: 3 4 5
>   Row [2]: 6 7 8
>   Bar
>   Row [0]: 0 1 2
>   Row [1]: 3 4 5
>   Row [2]: 6 7 8
>   Res
>   Row [0]: 15 19 23
>   Row [1]: 45 58 71
>   Row [2]: 75 97 119

Source is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Replace this method with a printf version for C compatibility*/
void print(double **mat, int x, int y)
{
  int r, c;
  for ( r = 0; r < x; r++ ) {
    std::cout << "Row [" << r << "]: ";
    for ( c = 0; c < y; c++ ) {
      std::cout << mat[r][c] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

void del(double **mat, int x)
{
  int r = 0;
  for ( r = 0; r < x; r++ ) {
      free( mat[r] );
    }
  free( mat );
}

double** createMatrix(int sizeX, int sizeY, int val=0)
{

  double **matrix;
  matrix = (double **)malloc( sizeX * sizeof( double * ) );
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeX; i++) {
    matrix[i] = (double *)malloc( sizeY * sizeof( double ) );
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < sizeY; j++) {
      if ( val == 0 ) {
        matrix[i][j] = 0;
      }
      else {
        matrix[i][j] = i * sizeY + j;
      }
    }
  }
  return matrix;
}

double **multiply(double **a, double **b, int xa, int ya, int xb, int yb)
{
  if ( ya != xb ) {
    printf( "Can't multiply incompatible matrices\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  double **c = createMatrix( xa, yb, 1 );
  int i,j,k;
  for ( i = 0; i < xa; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < yb; j++ ) {
      for ( k = 0; k < xb; k++ ) {
        c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  double **foo = createMatrix( 3, 3 );
  double **bar = createMatrix( 3, 3 );
  double **res = NULL;

  printf( "Foo: \n" );
  print( foo, 3, 3 );
  printf( "Bar: \n" );
  print( bar, 3, 3 );

  res = multiply( foo, bar, 3, 3, 3, 3);
  printf( "Res: \n" );

  if ( res ) {
    print( res, 3, 3 );
    del( res, 3 );
  }
  else {
    printf("Couldn't multiply see earlier error message!\n");
  }

  del( foo, 3 );
  del( bar, 3 );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a complete program. Could you write your solution in the language use by the OP instead, though?

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment and understand (this is why i refrained from using true C++  functionaility).  The only non-C thing I did was the print method which isn't central to the question. While C99 has introduced support for bool, I'll update that part. If someone else wants to edit my print method to use printf that's kosher with me. I just haven't used printf in ages. I'll make the rest of it ready.

Answer (score 1):

check the row length of matrix A and column length of matrix B is equal before  multiplication of matrix A and B.

Comment: Thanks sepideh was thinking this but forgot it initially and your post reminded me to incorporate it into my code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be convenient to have your `MatrixAllocate` return an identity matrix instead of a zero matrix. To do this, change the loop payload to

```
            matrix[i][j] = i==j? 1: 0;
```